# Error of HTML::link() in Laravel 5

Tags: html, hyperlink, laravel-5

I am using `echo HTML::link('/public', 'Insert New Record');` in one of my Controller function. Like below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\model\Report;
use App\Http\Requests; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class WelcomeController extends Controller 
{
     public function show_report()
     {
        echo HTML::link('/public', 'Insert New Record');  
     }
}
```

I am getting this error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\URL' not found` .

What will be the solution for this ??

Thanks

Comment: Please add more code for debugging.

Comment: Try `echo Html::link('/public','Insert New Record');`

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Illuminate component was removed from Laravel's core when it got to 5.0 (i think it was then...)

A group called the Laravel Collective have taken on the packages that have been removed from the core of laravel.

I believe the library from the the tutorial in aebersold's answer has been deprecated and moved laravelcollective/html. Installation instructions are here: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

new package name / version:
`"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"`

new things for your `app.php` config are:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    // ...
],

// ... and ...

'aliases' => [
    // ...
    'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
    // ...
],
```

`HTML::link($url, $title);` should then work.

Comment: The alias should be in all caps too, if you are to use `HTML::link`, that is, in the `config/app.php`:
`'HTML' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',`

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel HTML Helper has been disabled by default in Laravel 5.

Follow [this installation steps](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation) to reenable it.

On an additional note, you shouldn't echo in a controller, return the string instead.

Comment: Thanks @aebersold. I followed your tutorial it but failed. How do I produce a link ??

Comment: Sorry, my link was outdated. Check http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation